# Access Request Headers in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I'm using this [project](https://github.com/npalm/graphql-java-demo/) and specifically these 2 classes: [ApplicationStartup.java](https://github.com/npalm/graphql-java-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/ofouro/code/graphql/demo/ApplicationStartup.java) and [Application.java](https://github.com/npalm/graphql-java-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/ofouro/code/graphql/demo/Application.java).

I googled a bit and it looks like all other examples use a specific `/endpoint` in order to get request headers and I just have my app running on `localhost:8080` instead. But it looks like I do have `/graphql` endpoint so it should be possible to parse request's header.

Here are the contents of my `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: false

graphql.playground:
  mapping: /playground
  endpoint: /graphql
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is to get the current request header then below code will do that for you.

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()) .getRequest();

request.getHeader("Authorization");
```

Answer (score 1):

Any Spring controller can get access to headers as part of the method arguments using `@RequestHeader` annotation (docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html)):

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    public ResponseEntity<String> schedule(@RequestBody MyDto request,
                                           @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers)
{
   ...
}
```

If you don't have access to the controller code, you can implement a `OncePerRequestFilter` and access the headers from the underlying servlet request using @gnana's approach.